# '$\times$' or '$\otimes$' when writing $L$-functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Recently, I came across the Langlands correspondence theorem, there is the following line:

> $$L(s,\pi(\sigma) \times \pi(\tau)) = L(s,\sigma \otimes \tau), $$
> where $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are representations of the Weil group, and $\pi(\sigma)$ and $\pi(\tau)$ are representations of $GL_2(F)$.

My question is: Why is the first symbol '$\times$' while the second symbol is '$\otimes$'? Are these interchangeable?

Actually I have seen $L(s,\pi \otimes \chi)$ and $L(s,\pi \otimes f)$ (with $\pi$ representation, $\chi$ character, and $f$ modular form) in some places, but in other literature, I have seen authors write them as $L(s,\pi \times \chi)$ and $L(s,\pi \times f)$. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol $\times$ on the left-hand side is the Rankin-Selberg product. If $\pi$ and $\rho$ are automorphic representations of $\mathrm{GL}(m)$ and $\mathrm{GL}(n)$, respectively, then one can define the Rankin-Selberg $L$-function $L(s,\pi\times\rho)$. Conjecturally, there is an automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(mn)$ whose $L$-function is $L(s,\pi\times\rho)$, and $\pi\times\rho$ is supposed to denote this automorphic representation. For $m=n=2$ the conjecture was proved by Ramakrishnan (2000), so $\pi(\sigma)\times\pi(\tau)$ in the original post is a genuine automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(4)$. If $\pi\times\rho$ is known to exist, then it is reasonable to denote it by $\pi\otimes\rho$. In particular, this is the case when $\rho$ is a character ($n=1$): in this case, $\pi\otimes\rho$ is the automorphic representation $g\mapsto\pi(g)\rho(\det g)$.

The symbol $\otimes$ on the right-hand side is the usual tensor product of group representations.

Comment: Thank you very much! So all  '$\otimes$' can be replaced with '$\times$', right? (In fact I have seen people do this.)

Comment: @EulerLee For Galois (or Weil-Deligne) representations, I would stick to $\otimes$. For automorphic representations, $\times$ is a safe and good option.

Comment: I use $\otimes$ on the automorphic side too (at least when it's known to be automorphic).  You might see, e.g., $\pi \times \rho$ for a rep of say GL(2) x GL(2) and $\pi \otimes \rho$ for the functorial transfer to GL(4).

Comment: Isn't there a risk of confusion with the actual tensor product of the representations of GL(2) (maybe completed)? I guess this one might not be irreducible nor automorphic.

Comment: @Aurel I think the risk is negligible. If you talk about $L(s,\pi\times\rho)$ or $L(s,\pi\otimes\rho)$, most people will think of the Rankin-Selberg $L$-function.

Comment: @GHfromMO Fair enough!